# Jquery - live('hover') and mousemove

Tags: jquery

i have a little problem with the hover function with mousemove.
But what is wrong?

working example -> http://www.jsfiddle.net/V9Euk/306/

```
$('.tip').live('hover', function(e)
{    
    if (e.type == 'mouseover')
    {
      $('#'+this.id+' .tooltip').show();
    }        
    if (e.type == 'mousemove')
    {
        alert('move');
         $('#'+this.id+' .tooltip').css({ left: e.pageX + 20, top: e.pageY + 20});
    }        
    if (e.type == 'mouseout')
    {
        $('.tooltip').hide();
    }    
});
```

Comment: please check the working example. He did not start the mousemove

Comment: *Little problem* is not a very good problem description. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `hover` event - you need to instead include all three events which you used, like this:

```
$('.tip').live('mouseout mousemove mouseover', function(e)
```

See the [jQuery documentations](http://api.jquery.com/live/) example on multiple events in `live()`:

```
$('.hoverme').live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
  if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
    // do something on mouseover
  } else {
    // do something on mouseout
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey Yi Jiang, as always... Thank you very much! Peter(Koh chang)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `hover()` maps to `mouseover` and `mouseleave), not the events you're using.

```
$("...").live("hover", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

is equivalent to:

```
$("...").live("mouseover mouseleave", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

If you want the `mousemove` event too you can use:

```
$("...").live("hover mousemove", function(e) {
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hah! You deleted the same question before, RIGHT after I was going to click **Post Answer**.

`.hover()` will never return mousemove, it will only return mouseenter/mouseleave.

You should directly bind to the mousemove event, using

```
$('.tip').live('mousemove', function(e) {
    // do stuff here
});
```